# How to make my textfield disappear in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How to hide a textfield? I want to make it disappear, not just hide it using a button. I already tried using `isHidden` on my textfield but the constraint looks so weird.

Comment: thanks for all the answers it's works but how to make it back to normal constraint when i click it again ? iam thinking to disable the constraint constant

Comment: When you have to show then again set the height constraint to particular height

Comment: yeaa i already try that but how about i disable the constraint ? i already try isActive to the constraint but when i enable then disable it again i got a fatal error

Comment: Disable means what? And why Do you need it

Comment: Thats simple. Make the height back to 30 and it will be resumed

Comment: @IndraSen Edited the answer for you. Hope that helps you

Answer (score 2):

Simply set height constraint to Textfield. Take IBOutlet of height constraint. Where you are hiding textfield, set height constraint 0.

```
textfieldHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```

If you have show then again set height constraint to particular hegiht like:-

```
textfieldHeightConstraint.constant = 30
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

**Step :1:-** Take the height Constraint of TextField:

[image]

**Step :-** 2 Assign the height to 0

```
txtNameHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```

This step will simply make your height to 0 and it will look like `disappear`

Hope this helps.

### Edit To show it back again

The idea is simple. If you want to show that again, simply make the height back to 30

**To hide:**

```
txtNameHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```

**To show:**

```
txtNameHeightConstraint.constant = 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, put your textfield into stackView and make hide the textfield. all constraint will be manage it self.

Answer (score 0):

Add a subview to the view and place the textfield inside. Use the alpha property to hide the subview.